# Getting a blank page after deploying JSS-React application on server (Tech preview 4)

Tags: jss, placeholders

I am Getting a blank page after deploying JSS-React application on server (Tech preview 4) with two console warning

```
1) Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response 
https://www.google.com/ with MIME type text/html. 
See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

2)PlaceholderCommon.js:57 Placeholder 'jss-main' was not found in the current rendering 
data {
  "name": "home",
  "displayName": "home",
  "fields": {
    "pageTitle": {
      "value": "ABC"
    }
  },
  "databaseName": "web",
  "deviceId": "fe5d7fdf-89c0-4d99-9aa3-b5fbd009c9f3",
  "itemId": "2cf4bbda-b6b1-561c-b048-5043e08764a7",
  "itemLanguage": "en",
  "itemVersion": 1,
  "layoutId": "ebbdb4b8-0a5b-5fd2-b3d8-397a8b397033",
  "templateId": "c8a950cd-ede5-5290-8fb7-a591ccbff2de",
  "templateName": "App Route",
  "placeholders": {}
}
```

can someone help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

For the placeholder error, check the following:

1. Root-level placeholders need to be defined in `package.json`, in the `config.rootPlaceholders` property.
2. Component-level placeholders need to be defined in the component's manifest definition (in the object you pass to `manifest.addComponent`).

For the `CORS` error, check the following:

If you are using https to access your site, make sure the endpoints in `scjssconfig.json` are also defined with https.